# Android : Set Notification Image

Tags: android

In my project, i'm using pushbot to push the notifications to the device. Now it is displaying the app logo but i want a particular say "R.drawable.alert" to be displayed instead of the app logo. So how to go about it. Below i'm posting the code for the Custom Handler class. I'm working with pushbots.

Custom Handler class

```
    public class customHandler extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "customHandler";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "action=" + action);
        // Handle Push Message when opened
        if (action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_OPEN)) {
            //Check for Pushbots Instance
            Pushbots pushInstance = Pushbots.sharedInstance();
            if(!pushInstance.isInitialized()){
                com.pushbots.push.utils.Log.d("Initializing Pushbots.");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(context.getApplicationContext());
            }

            //Clear Notification array
            if(PBNotificationIntent.notificationsArray != null){
                PBNotificationIntent.notificationsArray = null;
            }

            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_OPEN);
            android.util.Log.w(TAG, "User clicked notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));

            //Report Opened Push Notification to Pushbots
            if(Pushbots.sharedInstance().isAnalyticsEnabled()){
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().reportPushOpened( (String) PushdataOpen.get("PUSHANALYTICS"));
            }

            //Start lanuch Activity
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            resultIntent.putExtras(intent.getBundleExtra("pushData"));
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().startActivity(resultIntent);

            // Handle Push Message when received
        }else if(action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE)){
            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE);
            android.util.Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do it ,Upload icon to server, and in server pushbots >"Custom Payload" ,write in `Key=largeIcon`, and `Value=URL` of icon.

**Image Example**
[image]

More information in here: [PushBots tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuHmjLgPmpc)